# Uniform convergence of series and continuity of $f$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series, uniform-convergence

This is from Ross's Elementary Analysis Textbook:

The series $(2^{-n})(x^n)$ from $n=1$ to $n= \infty$ represents a continuous function on $(-2,2)$, but the convergence isn't uniform.

He points out that for all $a$ with $0<a<2$, the series converges uniformly on $[-a,a]$ by the  Weierstrass M Test. Thus $f$ is continuous on $(-2,2)$

But then he points out $f$ does not converge uniformly on $(-2,2)$ because the following condition doesn't apply: $\sup (2^{-n})(x^n)< \epsilon$ for all $n>N$ and for all $x \in (-2,2)$

Can someone explain these two seemingly contradictory results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rough intuition is that uniform convergence on $[-a,a]$ for all $0<a<2$ does not imply uniform convergence on the open interval $(-2,2)$ because the bound you need for uniform convergence on $[-a,a]$ blows up to infinity as $a$ approaches $2$. And this is actually what happens: in the interval $[-a,a]$ we can uniformly bound the partial sums of the series by
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n 2^{-k}a^k = \frac{(a/2)^{n+1}-1}{a/2-1}.
$$
What happens as $a\to2$?

What's happening here is that the series
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty 2^{-k}x^k
$$
diverges at $x=2$: we can make it arbitrarily large by choosing $x$ close enough to $2$. In other words, there is no way to uniformly bound the series as $x$ approaches $2$.

By comparison, the series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k^2}
$$
converges uniformly in the interval $[-a,a]$ for every $0<a<1$, and *also* converges uniformly in the interval $[-1,1]$. Do you see why?

Comment: Is this correct:  if the radius of convergence is R, and the series converges at $x=R$ and $x=-R$, then the series converges uniformly on $[-R,R]$. If the radius of convergence is R, and x doesn't converge at $x=R$ or $x=-R$, then the series converges uniformly on $(-R,R)$. In the first case, $f$ is continuous on $[-R,R]$, in the second, $f$ is continuous on $(-R,R)$.

Comment: I think that in the first case you need to assume that the series converges *absolutely* at $x=R$ and $x=-R$. Otherwise, everything sounds good.